# Precision of Interval for PL/SQL Function value

Tags: oracle, plsql

Generally, when you specify a function the scale/precision/size of the return datatype is undefined.

For example, you say `FUNCTION show_price RETURN NUMBER` or `FUNCTION show_name RETURN VARCHAR2`.

You are not allowed to have `FUNCTION show_price RETURN NUMBER(10,2)` or `FUNCTION show_name RETURN VARCHAR2(20)`, and the function return value is unrestricted. [This is documented functionality.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_function.htm#sthref2705)

Now, I get an precision error (ORA-01873) if I push 9999 hours (about 400 days) into the following. The limit is because [the default days precision is 2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#i78291)

```
DECLARE
  v_int INTERVAL DAY (4) TO SECOND(0);
  FUNCTION hhmm_to_interval return INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND IS
    v_hhmm INTERVAL DAY (4) TO SECOND(0);
  BEGIN
    v_hhmm := to_dsinterval('PT9999H');
    RETURN v_hhmm;
    --
  END hhmm_to_interval;
BEGIN
  v_int := hhmm_to_interval;
end;
/
```

and it won't allow the precision to be specified directly as part of the datatype returned by the function.

```
DECLARE
  v_int INTERVAL DAY (4) TO SECOND(0);
  FUNCTION hhmm_to_interval return INTERVAL DAY (4) TO SECOND IS
    v_hhmm INTERVAL DAY (4) TO SECOND(0);
  BEGIN
    v_hhmm := to_dsinterval('PT9999H');
    RETURN v_hhmm;
    --
  END hhmm_to_interval;
BEGIN
  v_int := hhmm_to_interval;
end;
/
```

I can use a SUBTYPE

```
DECLARE
  subtype t_int is INTERVAL DAY (4) TO SECOND(0);
  v_int INTERVAL DAY (4) TO SECOND(0);
  FUNCTION hhmm_to_interval return t_int IS
    v_hhmm INTERVAL DAY (4) TO SECOND(0);
  BEGIN
    v_hhmm := to_dsinterval('PT9999H');
    RETURN v_hhmm;
    --
  END hhmm_to_interval;
BEGIN
  v_int := hhmm_to_interval;
end;
/
```

Any drawbacks to the subtype approach ?

Any alternatives (eg some place to change a default precision) ?

Working with 10gR2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No real drawbacks that I can think of.  I think it would be a bit more clear if the working variables were declarred as instances of the subtype, e.g.:

```
DECLARE 
  subtype t_int is INTERVAL DAY (4) TO SECOND(0);

  v_int t_int;

  FUNCTION hhmm_to_interval return t_int IS 
    v_hhmm t_int; 
  BEGIN 
    v_hhmm := to_dsinterval('PT9999H'); 
    RETURN v_hhmm; 
  END hhmm_to_interval; 

BEGIN 
  v_int := hhmm_to_interval;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_int=' || v_int);
end;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Yes, that code looks cleaner and with just one place to change the precision.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provides some build-in subtypes for that purpose, see [Avoiding Truncation Problems Using Date and Time Subtypes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/datatypes.htm#CIHIJCDG)

They are:

```
TIMESTAMP_UNCONSTRAINED
TIMESTAMP_TZ_UNCONSTRAINED
TIMESTAMP_LTZ_UNCONSTRAINED
YMINTERVAL_UNCONSTRAINED
DSINTERVAL_UNCONSTRAINED
```